# Probability and Random Variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, definite-integrals, random-variables

[image]
Hi, I was trying to understand this example in the book. In the first part of the question, We've to find p.d.f (**probability density function**). For that, we take the derivative of the given distribution function **F(x)** and it is done. But in another part of the question we've to find **P(|X| < 1.5)** and we have to integrate for p.d.f (Probability distribution function),      **Now I am confused about the ranges of those integrals.**
Why we must divide the range into these four pieces i.e, **(-∞, -1.5), (-1.5 , 0), (0 , 1), (1 , 1.5)**? for integration. My question is, if We're trying to find **P(|X| < 1.5)** then why do we must divide the range of integration into these four pieces? Why is the range is going from -∞ to -1.5 (in the first integral) and not to 0?
I'm confused about *where did **-1.5** come from?* I mean, why we are including **-1.5** in the range of integrals? I am assuming, it is because of the || (mod) thing. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: You do not need to. Anything equal to zero does not contribute to the integral

Comment: Sir, Could you please elaborate, Why -1.5 is included in the range of the first integral?

Comment: Rewinding quite a lot, you don't need to integrate the pdf here to find P(|X|<1.5).  you're already given the cdf, F(x).  So you can simply take P(|X|<1.5) = P(-1.5 < X < 1.5) = F(1.5)-F(-1.5) and plug that into the piecewise formula given.

But yeah, the integral from -infinity to -1.5 should NOT be included when computing P(-1.5 < X < 1.5).   That is a mistake in the textbook (which ends up not mattering because that integral is zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event $\{|X|<1.5\}$ is the same as the event $\{-1.5 < X<1.5\}$, therefore
$$
P(|X|<1.5) = P(-1.5 < X<1.5).$$
This explains where the $-1.5$ comes from.

The example is performing unnecessary steps in evaluating $P(-1.5<X<1.5)$. What the example should do next is refer to the formula
$$
P(a<X<b) = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$$ to obtain
$$P(-1.5<X<1.5) = \int_{-1.5}^{1.5}f(x)\,dx.$$
Since the p.d.f. $f$ is defined differently over the intervals $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$ and $(2,\infty)$, the next step would be to divide the range of integration $(-1.5, 1.5)$ into three pieces, $(-1.5,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1.5)$:
$$\int_{-1.5}^{1.5}f(x)\,dx
=\int_{-1.5}^{0}f(x)\,dx
+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx
+\int_{1}^{1.5}f(x)\,dx
$$ and then substitute the proper values for $f(x)$ within those three ranges.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $|X|<1.5\iff -1.5<X<1.5.$ Also note for real-valued random variable $X$ having density $f$,

$$\int_Af(x)dx=P(X\in A)=E[1_{X\in A}]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{X\in A}f(x)dx.$$

Your textbook appears to be essentially using the second integral to compute $P(X\in A)$ where $A:=(-1.5,1.5)$. The textbook splits the integral into many integrals to account simultaneously for when the indicator is zero or one as well as the piecewise nature of the density. Interestingly, the textbook omits the integral $\int_{1.5}^\infty 1_{X\in A} f(x)dx$ (which would be zero anyway).

Bottom line: you can just compute the probability as

$$P(|X|<1.5)=\int_{-1.5}^{1.5}f(x)dx.$$ which, accounting for the piecewise nature of the density, can be computed easily as

$$\int_{-1.5}^{0}0dx+\int_{0}^{1}{4x \over 5}dx+\int_{1}^{1.5}{2 \over 5}(3-x)dx.$$